# update textview from internet

Tags: android, textview, server

I want to make a TextView or Imageview that request info from the internet, as if it was a newspapper that's updated daily, I want to do something similar but I don't know how.

I guess I should have a server or something but could someone explain me the process? and which server or what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 first you need to enable the permission in the android manifest
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
than you can use a textView like this
new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String path ="http://host.com/info.txt"; // your webpage with text
                URL u = null;
                try {
                    u = new URL(path);
                    HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
                    c.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    c.connect();
                    InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
                    final ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    in.read(buffer); // Read from Buffer.
                    bo.write(buffer); // Write Into Buffer.

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
                            text.setText(bo.toString());
                            try {
                                bo.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
 }.start();
```

Comment: where could I have a free webpage with this "section" "text"? will everything that's written on this website be returned to my application? the headers and so on will be returned too..

Comment: edit for the comment, I've created an account on a free server online but now on the cpanel I don't know what to create to communicate with the code you wrote above